# Does breaking Arduino code into functions take up more space/resources?

Tags: performance, arduino, firmware

Let's say I have this code below:

```
int led = 13;

void setup() {                
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}

void loop() {
  ledChange(HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  ledChange(LOW);
  delay(1000);
}

void ledChange(int pinState)  {
  digitalWrite(led, pinState);
}
```

Does moving `digitalWrite(led, pinState);` to its own function affect processing time?

Of course, performance doesn't matter with a single LED, but it could matter when every clock cycle counts (high sampling rates, lots of math in loops, etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are wasting a teensy amount of clock cycles. When you write `ledChange(LOW)`, it is compiled to a CALL type instruction (which tells the program counter register to jump to the location of the method).

So, this will basically compile to:

- Put `LOW` in some register or the stack
- jump to the location of `ledChange()`
- Fetch `led` from memory, and put it along with `LOW` somewhere
- jump to `digitalWrite()`
- do whatever is in `digitalWrite()`
- jump back
- jump back

Note that a `CALL` jump involves a lot of messing with the stack, and takes a lot longer than a regular `JMP` instruction.

On the other hand, doing just `digitalWrite(led,LOW)` will do:

- Fetch `led`,`LOW` from somewhere on the memory and put them somewhere accessible
- jump to `ditigalWrite()`
- do whatever is in `digitalWrite()`
- jump back

I'm not entirely sure how arguments are passed in the corresponding compiled code, it's probably a *part* of the call. Also note that compilers vary, and some are smarter than others.

You can see that your encapsulation of the function made the program take up more clock cycles every time you while running it. However, this isn't really worth optimizing; I don't see much capacity in such encapsulation to slow down the Arduino. Besides, like I mentioned, some compilers optimize such things.

---

This has nothing to do with the function being a `void`. If it was an `int` function, it would be ever-so-slightly slower since storing the int before return involves a `MV` or stack operation (forgot which).

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler automatically in-line trivial functions? I would have thought compile time optimisations would have been more important on an embedded device like the Arduino than elsewhere.

Comment: @MarkBooth: Like I mentioned, some compilers optimize such things. I'm not sure if the Arduino compiler does that.

Comment: It does. It is [uses avr-gcc underneath](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess)

Answer (score 8):

A function being defined as void simply informs the compiler / optimizer that there is no return value expected from the function.

There will thus be no code generated for saving or manipulating any return value.

This is not Arduino specific, it is a generic C behavior.

Comment: So, If I were to use the "Blink" example, Arduino would compile it exactly the same?

Comment: You'd have to ask the compiler developers or those familiar with the particular compiler (Arduino provides the IDE, not the compiler underlying it) for a definitive answer, but that is a very reasonable hypothesis. This isn't really an Arduino question beyond this point.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup avr-gcc to show the assembly output. Checking it out you can see that the return type of the function doesn't matter regarding the size of the code. If you don't return any value it won't generate extra code. However you will get compiler warnings, so it's nice to use `void` in this case.

If you use functions you will have likely shorter code, because you don't need to repeat the code in the function every time you need it (this means you'll need to have enough code in the function to offset the calls and return instructions - which is almost always the case). This will make the code *slightly* slower since it needs to execute the call and return instructions, however this most likely will be offset by the size reduction and the improvement in the code maintenance.

I hope I was clear enough, this seems a little convoluted :)